# Check the size of log files

Tags: unix

In unix using command `tail -f a.txt` we can monitor the growth of the log-files. Let's say logfile
name is `a.txt` and it can hold the data upto `10mb` . now it's full

So what i have to do ? can i use  `logrotate` something there is another logfiles i have created

```
b.txt
```

how to assign b.txt and i can check growth in b.txt .

apart from this question , i have one more question

```
(1) what's the maximum size of log-files we can create
```

Comment: The answer to your another question, *I don't think there is any limit for size of log-files, it mostly depends on File System Type and Remaining disk space you are having.*

Comment: Okay , but how to create logfile simply i can use "touch filename.txt"